# ttk.Button cleaner change stated reaction

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, code-cleanup, ttkwidgets

My code works but would like to have a cleaner. I have 24 ON and OFF buttons. When an ON button is clicked, it will be disabled and green, while the OFF button is greyed out and "!disabled". Is there a way to do this without making a ton of ON and OFF methods? Currently i have 48 methods, styles, etc. amounting to 800 lines of code. I know there has to be a better way...

Here is an example:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
class APP:
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title('APP')
        master.resizable(False, False)

        self.style = ttk.Style()

        self.frame_header = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_header.pack()

        self.frame_stations = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_stations.pack()
        # default style and text of button
        self.style.configure('n1_on.TButton', foreground='#d2d2d2',font=('Arial', 15,'bold'))
        self.style.configure('n1_off.TButton', foreground='#d2d2d2', font=('Arial',15,'bold'))
        self.style.configure('n2_on.TButton',  foreground='#d2d2d2',font=('Arial', 15,'bold'))
        self.style.configure('n2_off.TButton', foreground='#d2d2d2', font=('Arial', 15,'bold'))
        # changes state (disabled) and font color when clocked
        self.style.map('n1_on.TButton', foreground=[('disabled','green')])
        self.style.map('n1_off.TButton', foreground=[('disabled','red')])
        self.style.map('n2_off.TButton', foreground=[('disabled','red')])
        self.style.map('n2_on.TButton', foreground=[('disabled','green')])

        ttk.Label(self.frame_stations, text="BUTTONS").grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=5)
        #buttons created adn location
        self.n1_on = ttk.Button(self.frame_stations, text='ON', style='n1_on.TButton', command=self.n1_on_state,)
        self.n1_on.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.n2_on = ttk.Button(self.frame_stations, text='ON', style='n2_on.TButton', command=self.n2_on_state)
        self.n2_on.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.n1_off = ttk.Button(self.frame_stations, text='OFF', style= 'n1_off.TButton', command=self.n1_off_state)
        self.n1_off.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.n2_off= ttk.Button(self.frame_stations, text='OFF', style='n2_off.TButton', command=self.n2_off_state)
        self.n2_off.grid(row=2, column=2)

    def n1_on_state(self):
        print('n1 turned on')
        self.n1_on.state(['disabled'])
        self.n1_off.state(['!disabled'])

    def n2_on_state(self):
        print('n2 turned on')
        self.n2_on.state(['disabled'])
        self.n2_off.state(['!disabled'])

    def n1_off_state(self):
        print('n1_turned off')
        self.n1_on.state(['!disabled'])
        self.n1_off.state(['disabled'])

    def n2_off_state(self):
        print('n2 turned off')
        self.n2_on.state(['!disabled'])
        self.n2_off.state(['disabled'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just define it like this? Why do you have to define the function every time for each button?

```
# Define this above your code and pass it the buttons you want to turn on or off
def turn_off_buttons(turn_off, turn_on):
    # Also when we want to inform the user we usually put the 'print' statement after the work is finished 
    # print(f'{turn_off} turned off') (Not here)
    # turn_on.state(['!disabled']) 
    # turn_off.state(['disabled'])
    # I would suggest you to use 'config' instead of state since it is more applicable
    turn_off.config(state=DISABLED)
    turn_on.config(state=NORMAL)
    print(f'{turn_off} turned off')
```

Example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


# Define this above your code and pass it the buttons you want to turn on or off
def turn_off_buttons(turn_off, turn_on):
    # Also when we want to inform the user we usually put the 'print' statement after the work is finished 
    # print(f'{turn_off} turned off') (Not here)
    # turn_on.state(['!disabled']) 
    # turn_off.state(['disabled'])
    # I would suggest you to use 'config' instead of state since it is more applicable
    turn_off.config(state=DISABLED)
    turn_on.config(state=NORMAL)
    print(f'{turn_off} turned off')

class TurnOnOff:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("550x280")
        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self.root, text="Turn On", command=lambda: turn_off_buttons(self.button1, self.button2))
        self.button2 = ttk.Button(self.root, text="Turn Off", command=lambda: turn_off_buttons(self.button2, self.button1))
        self.button1.pack(pady=5)
        self.button2.pack(pady=5)
        self.root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TurnOnOff()
```

Comment: Thank you, that saved me hundreds of lines of code. Thank you

Comment: @rayguess22, any time